# ctypes character pointers with same byte string points same location

Tags: python, string, pointers, output, ctypes

I am creating two ctypes character pointers with same byte string via:

```
import ctypes as ct

var1 = ct.c_char_p(b'.'*80)
var2 = ct.c_char_p(b'.'*80)

# how I check the values:
api = ct.CDLL('api.dll')
api.function1(var1, var2)

# values of the vars are changed after running the above function
print(var1.value.decode(), var2.value.decode())
```

I am running a `CDLL.function` which changes values in the locations where `var1` and `var2` points. I was expecting, that if I would create 2 different pointers like above, these pointers would point a different location in memory. However, they do point to the same location, because when I check the values of these variables they are the same.

When I create the `var2` with different character (e.g.: `b'*'80`) instead of `b'.'*80`, then it works. Is there a better way to create `var1` and `var2`, so that both of these pointers would point a different location?

Comment: You can use the `id` function to confirm that these variables do not point to the same location in memory (or at least they don't for me)

Comment: “they do point to the same location”.  If I remember correctly, this is a compiler (bytecode compiler) optimisation which ‘sees’ two identical strings, and thus points both symbols to the same memory location.

Comment: @MarkChackerian could you eleborate the id-function?

Comment: @oakca - Here is a link to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) for `id()`.

Comment: *"when I check the values of these variables they are the same"* - You should show how you checked.

Comment: @MarkChackerian you are correct, they have different id values, but from the values of these variables, I know they are pointing to the same location...

Comment: You haven't really demonstrated that the two variables are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b'.'*80` is an *immutable* string and Python (as an implementation detail) is completely free to re-use the object and give you the same pointer for both `var1` and `var2`.  If your C function is changing it, that is undefined behavior.

Instead, use `ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'.'*80)` to create a writable buffer.

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#fundamental-data-types):

> You should be careful, however, not to pass [`c_char_p`] to functions expecting pointers to mutable memory. If you need mutable memory blocks, `ctypes` has a `create_string_buffer()` function which creates these in various ways. The current memory block contents can be accessed (or changed) with the raw property; if you want to access it as NUL terminated string, use the value property.